# Google USB driver cannot be found

Tags: usb-drivers, android-sdk

I am trying to connect my phone (archos 40 titanium) on my computer (W7 x64) using USB Debug mode (to make a backup). Here is what I've done:

1. I've downloaded google SDK and extracted it in `C:/adtbundle`
2. I ran `SDK Manager.exe` and enusured google USB driver was up to date
3. I right clicked on `Computer` (in start menu) and I selected `Devices`in the right panel of the new window.
4. In other devices I select `A40ti` and right clicked, then `Update driver`.
5. Then, I choose `Browse my computer for driver software` and then browse. I selected `C:\adtbundle\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`.
6. I get something like `Windows can't found any drivers` (I am translating since my system is in French).

When I run `adb devices` it shows an empty list.

**How to install them and get adb working?**

EDIT:
Here are the new steps:

1. I downloaded [from here](http://www.archos.com/us/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html) the driver, which I extracted in an new `archos`folder next to google's like this:

   - `C:/adtbundle/sdk/extras/`

     - `android/`
     - `archos/`

       - `amd64/`
       - `i386/`
       - `adb_winusb_driver.zip`
       - `android_winusb.inf`
       - `androidwinusb86.cat`
       - `androidwinusba64.cat`
       - `source.properties`
     - `google/`
2. Same as 3-5 but with path `C:\adtbundle\sdk\extras\archos`
3. Same as 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's USB Drivers are for the Google reference devices (Nexus series) only. You'll need to install Archos' drivers. They can be found on Archos' [support page](http://www.archos.com/us/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html) with instructions on how to install them and get ADB working.

- Install the drivers
- Add the vendor ID 0x0e79 to your adb_usb.ini, e.g. `echo 0x0e79 >> "%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini"`
- Done!

Edit: The driver's from the support page didn't work, but [these](https://mega.co.nz/#!IU4kmLxA!Wn4yABhV20OKEpsoW_KO9p1nS126CpU9OpSKsI99jis) did. They came from an unreliable source and had other drivers from 2005 with them, but I stripped them and repacked. Feel free to verify with virus scanners.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still get that message, please see edit

Comment: Did you try unzipping the ADB driver package `adb_winusb_driver.zip`?

Comment: Yeah, that's the files just next to it (android_winusb.inf...)

Comment: Hmmm... If I remember correctly, my Android devices showed up as Android Debug Bridge even without the drivers when they were in ADB mode, are you sure you have it on in the phone?

Comment: Yes, I think so, I've checked it and I can see it in my notification bar

Comment: I managed to select the inf file, but it says my device isn't compatible or it is my system that isn't. It is x64 with an old AMD athlon 5000+

Comment: Weird. I found another driver package, looks a bit more shady but I opened it on my Mac and there doesn't seem to be anything evidently malicious. Try at your own risk [here](http://singledrivers.blogspot.fi/2014/02/archos-40-45-50-53-titanium-usb-driver.html)

Comment: 3/46 have antivirus have detected a threat https://www.virustotal.com/fr/file/47d774cdda79f29bbf21c899f0ca68779775a25a3556dd159928d79233c62e40/analysis/1403953954/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15406/discussion-between-onik-and-vinz243).